# TLS connection for a SMTP server

Tags: mailing, smtp

Our live CIVICRM environment is CiviCRM 5.67.1, Joomla 4.4.2, PHP 8.1, hosted on Siteground.  We are changing to a SMTP server for our CIVICRM mail.  Our mail provider wants us to use a TLS connection.  I have attached 2 screenshots - one for the settings in CiviCRM for outbound mail; the second is the result of clicking Save and Test email.  How do we make this work? [image: Attachment 1]  [image: Attachment 2]

Comment: The error says "authentication failed". Is it the right username/password? You could also try "SMTP port" 587 instead of 465 since there's two versions of encryption and one of them uses the 587 port.

Comment: They are the correct credentials.  CIVICRM can handle TLS, correct?  If so, do I have the nomenclature in the SMTP server field in the screenshots correct?

Comment: I just tried it on a different server and it works and I can see it uses TLS. Yes `ssl://` is correct. Maybe your password has special characters in it? Sometimes that causes problems.